# R Frailtypack abnormally terminates

Tags: r

In my data I have 13000 patients from 25 centers. In order to model the correlation among patients by centers, I choose the shared frailty model in frailtypack.

Here is a small subset of my data.

```
   Subject.ID frailty_status  Center   AS.Years Age Year.Of.Diagnosis Number.of.biopsy Gleason.Score PSA
1    1.000001              0 E  8.5420945  54                15                1         <4+<4 5.7
2    1.000002              0 A  6.8336756  67                16                1         <4+<4 8.0
3    1.000003              1 B  1.5879535  58                15                1         <4+<4 3.1
4    1.000004              1 A  2.4969199  69                16                1         <4+<4 3.0
5    1.000005              0 E  8.9691992  65                15                1         <4+<4 5.1
6    1.000006              0 F  8.2984257  61                15                1         <4+<4 0.9
7    1.000007              1 C  3.7782341  68                16                1         <4+<4 9.6
8    1.000008              0 E  7.1101985  72                14                1         <4+<4 4.5
9    1.000009              1 D  7.0527036  71                14                1         <4+<4 3.9
10   1.000010              1 B  4.6379192  75                16                1         <4+<4 5.5
11   1.000011              0 A  8.7310062  62                16                1         <4+<4 4.5
12   1.000012              0 E  8.0000000  73                16                1         <4+<4 3.0
13   1.000013              0 E  1.0513347  64                16                2         <4+<4 2.3
14   1.000014              0 E  6.2094456  67                16                1         <4+<4 4.5
15   1.000015              1 A  0.3641342  62                16                2         <4+<4 7.7
16   1.000016              0 B  5.3470226  54                16                1         <4+<4 3.8
17   1.000017              1 B  1.5195072  63                16                1         <4+<4 6.1
18   1.000018              1 C  2.4750171  59                16                2         <4+<4 8.5
19   1.000019              0 D  7.4113621  67                15                1         <4+<4 5.5
20   1.000020              0 D  8.4654346  60                16                1         <4+<4 9.9
21   1.000021              2 E  5.6919918  71                14                1         <4+<4 5.5
22   1.000022              0 A  7.4606434  55                15                1         <4+<4 4.7
23   1.000023              0 A  5.1252567  62                15                1         <4+<4 0.5
24   1.000024              0 F  7.1184120  60                15                1         <4+<4 3.0
25   1.000025              1 F  6.3244353  65                15                1         <4+<4 3.1
26   1.000026              0 F 13.7796030  66                10                2         <4+<4 1.8
27   1.000027              1 D  1.9822040  74                15                1         <4+<4 4.7
28   1.000028              1 D  4.0355921  65                16                1         <4+<4 6.1
29   1.000029              1 D  4.8432580  73                13                1         <4+<4 3.3
30   1.000030              1 D  1.7850787  63                16                1         <4+<4 4.3
```

My code

```
frailty.fit <- frailtyPenal(formula = Surv(AS.Years, frailty_status) ~ cluster(Center) + Age + 
                                      Year.Of.Diagnosis + PSA.at.inclusion + Number.of.biopsy + Gleason.Score,
                        data = cmp.dat, Frailty = TRUE, n.knots = 4, kappa = 1000, cross.validation = TRUE)
```

I get the error message `"previous R session was abnormally terminated due to an unexpected crash."` I've tried different values of `n.knots` like `5, 6, 7, 8` and `kappa` as `1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000`, but still receive the same error message. I am using R 3.2.3, frailpack 2.9.4, Ubuntu 14.04, 16G memory.

I would appreciate some of light to this problem.

Comment: Sounds more like an advisory message. Have you considered deleting teh `.RData` file and starting with a "clean slate"?

Comment: @42- Each time I tried different parameters, only the data and frailtypack package were loaded.

Comment: R loads an invisible file named .Rdata that stores objects made and saved from prior sessions.

Comment: @42- Thank you for the suggestion. But the error is still there.

Comment: frailtypack is a desaster. There are only three results that I got from two days trying to get the package to work: (1) "Problem in the loglikelihood computation....Please verify your dataset." (2) "Model did not converge." or (3) Results that make no sense whatsover. Even slight modifications of the sample data provided by the athors cause these errors. My advice: Do not touch it!